# prettify will cause "script is busy" warning if the code is long

Tags: javascript, prettify, busy-loop

I'm using [prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) by Google.
How to fix?

Comment: How long is your code? (It will help others.)

Answer (score 1):

Optimize `prettify` to make it faster, or make the code you're highlighting shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper solution, but I simply disable prettify if the code is too long.